# Proof irrelevance in COQ

Tags: coq

I am thinking about proof irrelevance in COQ. 
One provable statement says:

> If equality of a type is decidable then there can be only one proof for the equality statement, namely reflexivity.

I wonder if its possible to construct types with more than one equality proof in COQ. Therefore I ask if the following construct is consistent?

```
(*it is known that f=g is undecidable in COQ *)    
Definition f(n:nat) := n.
Definition g(n:nat) := n+0.

Axiom p1: f=g.
Axiom p2: f=g.

Axiom nonirrelevance:p1<>p2.
```

What me puzzles here is the fact that by introducing p1 I made the equality f=g decidable and therefore it should only have one proof! What is my error in reasoning here?

Is that all a pure COQ behaviour or is it similar in HOTT?

Comment: Related, I think: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/prove-proof-irrelevance-in-coq

Comment: I think your error in reasoning is that `p1` does not make equality over the type `nat -> nat` decidable, so proof irrelevance is not implied.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing several things.

The provable statement you are speaking of can be found in https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.html and is

```
Theorem eq_proofs_unicity A (eq_dec : forall x y : A, x = y \/ x <> y) (x : A) : 
    forall (y:A) (p1 p2:x = y), p1 = p2.
```

Now what is quite interesting is the type of `eq_dec`. First of all, it doesn't even really ask for equality to be decidable, it just asks for it to be true or false which is way less stronger than `{x = y} + {x <> y}`

Then notice that it doesn't ask this just for the x and y to prove the equality irrevelance of, it ask this property for all functions.

So you would need to prove your contradiction that `forall (f g : nat -> nat), f = g \/ f <> g` which you cannot. p1 is just a proof that `f = g \/ f <> g` for your specific f and g.
Notice though that if you could, it would just mean that there is no way to build a system in which you can compare functions and yet have multiple ways which are provably different to check them.

Finally, for P to be undecidable only means that there is no constructible functions over `{P} + {~P}` yet, it doesn't mean that adding one as an axiom leads to a contradiction. Just adding that in case it wasn't clear.

Comment: I do not understand your second sentence starting with "First of all...". Having a term from x=y \/ x<>y for each x,y is exactly what decidability means, isn't it?

Comment: Decidability is `{x = y}  + {x <> y}`. This means there is an algorithm capable of *deciding* wether those terms are equal or not. `x = y \/ x <> y` just means "either they are equal, either they are not, but heck if I am telling you which". You cannot know if the terms are equal or not when you have `x = y \/ x <> y`, that is to say it is not *constructive*. On the opposite, `{x = y} + {x <> y}` is.

Comment: You are confusing me now: Coq.Logic.Decidable defines *Definition decidable (P:Prop) := P \/ ~ P*.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not realize. In every Coq formalization I saw, decidable was always assumed to be `{P} + {~P}` (ssreflect does so for instance), guess I should have checked that. Anyway, I was just mentioning that this was *weak* decidability, not an effective one.

Comment: This is very weird though, since the very notion of decidability is bound with algorithms, which the `Prop` type isn't

Comment: Every statement in a constructive logic (e.g Coq) is bound to an algorithm. This is the essence of the Curry-Howard isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, but Coq handles non-constructive logic as well, like classical logic, by the mean of axioms. `Prop` was never intended to be a constructive type, that can be seen by the fact that deconstructing over a `Prop` hypothesis is impossible when constructing an inhabitant of a `Set` like a natural, or by the fact that program extraction over `Prop` is impossible.